# Instanced drawing with texture atlas

Tags: c++, opengl

I am currently trying to create a tilemap using instanced drawing. I have been able to draw multiple instances of a tile by sending the vertices corresponding to the geometry combined with the texture coordinates and the offsets of each tiles in a separate VBO and using the attribute divisor.

This however allows me to use only one texture. So I splitted the texture coordinates from the vertices and created a separate VBO like for the offsets, but it doesn't generate the expected results. Let's say the coordinates I send are the coordinates that match the first texture in the atlas for the first tile and the coordinates that match the second texture for the other tiles, if I use `glAttributeDivisor(1, 0)`, all the tiles use only the first texture. If I use any other value, I get some sort of checker pattern with only one pixel of each texture used for the entire tile.

Here's what it does when the attribute divisior is 0: [image: Divisor is 0]
And this is when the attribute divisor is at 1: [image: Divisor is 1]
Normally, the first tile in the bottom left corner should be a grass tile, like when the divisor is 0, and all the others should be a dirt tile.

This is what I do to create the buffers:

```
TileMap::TileMap(std::vector<glm::vec2> positions, std::vector<glm::vec2> texCoords, glm::vec2 tileSize,
                 std::shared_ptr<graphics::Shader> shader,
                 std::shared_ptr<graphics::Texture> texture) :
m_positions(positions), m_texCoords(texCoords), m_tileSize(tileSize), m_shader(shader), m_texture(texture) {
    m_model = glm::mat4();
    m_model = glm::scale(m_model, glm::vec3(tileSize, 1.0f));

    GLfloat vertices[] =
    {
        // Positions
        1.0f, 1.0f,     // Top Right
        1.0f, 0.0f,     // Bottom Right
        0.0f, 0.0f,     // Bottom Left
        0.0f, 1.0f      // Top Left
    };

    GLuint indices[] =
    {
        0, 1, 3,
        1, 2, 3
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &m_vao);
    glGenBuffers(1, &m_vbo);
    glGenBuffers(1, &m_ebo);

    glGenBuffers(1, &m_textureVbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_textureVbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec2) * m_texCoords.size(), &m_texCoords[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &m_instanceVbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_instanceVbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::vec2) * m_positions.size(), &m_positions[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    glBindVertexArray(m_vao);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_vbo);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_ebo);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_textureVbo);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_instanceVbo);
        glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        glVertexAttribDivisor(1, 0);
        glVertexAttribDivisor(2, 1);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

And this is how I generate the tilemap:

```
std::vector<glm::vec2> positions;
std::vector<glm::vec2> texCoords;
bool test = false;
for(float i = 0.0f; i < 7.0f; i++) {
    for(float j = 0.0f; j < 7.0f; j++) {
        positions.push_back(glm::vec2(j, i));

        if(test){
            texCoords.push_back(glm::vec2(1.0f, 1.0f)); // Top Right
            texCoords.push_back(glm::vec2(1.0f, 0.0f)); // Bottom Right
            texCoords.push_back(glm::vec2(0.5f, 0.0f)); // Bottom Left
            texCoords.push_back(glm::vec2(0.5f, 1.0f)); // Top Left
        } else {
            texCoords.push_back(glm::vec2(0.5f, 1.0f)); // Top Right
            texCoords.push_back(glm::vec2(0.5f, 0.0f)); // Bottom Right
            texCoords.push_back(glm::vec2(0.0f, 0.0f)); // Bottom Left
            texCoords.push_back(glm::vec2(0.0f, 1.0f)); // Top Left
        }

        test = true; //This is just to test the texture switching after the first tile
    }
}

graphics::TileMap tileMap(positions, texCoords, glm::vec2(64.0f), shader, texture);
```

I am not really familiar with OpenGl so I have absolutely no idea what is causing this nor what to use so that each quad read the 4 texture coordinates that should by tied to them.

Comment: One texture without any texture coordinate manipulation is sufficient if you have hardware access to array textures. _An implementation that supports vertex attrib divisors should support them._ This approach is preferred to atlasing in a lot of applications because packing and border pixels are not necessary.

Comment: @Andon How exactly can I implement a texture array like you say? I have searched for a long time before about how I should implement my textures and the only things I could find that have real explained examples were for texture atlases. I could only find some instructions on the opengl wiki however I don't fully understand what's going on there.

Comment: They are treated like a special case of 3D texture, you have z-many slices of WxH. You use a `sampler2DArray` and give it 3D texture coordinates (the first 2 are regular normalized coords and the third is an index into the array slice). The whole thing works ideally when each of the textures in your tilemap has the same resolution.

Comment: @Andron So essentially, instead of merging all the textures in a single file and a single texture unit, I should just load all the files, load them in a 3D texture and simply refer to each using the 3rd coordinate and keep the other 2 constant from (0,0) to (1,1)?

Comment: Effectively, yes. I don't know your entire use-case, but this allows you to use linear filtering on your texture atlas without having to add border pixels around each packed tile. There are a lot of benefits to doing it this way.

Comment: @Andron I see, that was one problem that I had, I had to change from linear filtering to nearest to get rid of the texture bleeding. Concerning the VBO, is there any major changes that I need to take care considering that I will have 2 constant and 1 variable coordinates or what I have would work with just a few changes?

Comment: @OliPro007: "*load them in a 3D texture*" No, you load them into an [*array texture*](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture). While they seem conceptually like 3D textures, they are *not* 3D textures.

Comment: @NicolBolas Just a poor choice of word on my part, rather the 3D texture function with the 2D texture array flag (if that's how the macro's purpose is called). I think I have found a good example now after a bit more research on texture arrays specifically, I just need to adapt it to instanced drawing.

Comment: @Andron It all works correctly now with the texture array. Thanks a lot!