# OpenGL 3.2 Why am I getting INVALID_ENUM error for glTexStorage3D?

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering

```
stbi_uc* data = stbi_load(path, &width, &height, NULL, 4);
if (data == NULL) {
    return false;
}
gl_flush_errors();

glGenTextures(1, &id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, id);
glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL_RGBA, 50, 50, 1);
```

This is the portion of my code where the INVALID_ENUM error is coming from, which I've narrowed down to the glTexStorage3D call. I'm also experiencing an INVALID_VALUE error directly after this block of code with:

```
glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

My goal here is to set up a texture array with my working tile instancing so I can render my tilemap in one draw call. I'm experiencing the same issue as here:
[Instanced drawing with texture atlas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028563/instanced-drawing-with-texture-atlas)

However, I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly at the moment so any help or direction would be appreciated. These are my shaders as well in case they're the cause of the issue:

Fragment Shader

```
#version 330
// From vertex shader
in vec2 uvcoord;

// Application data
uniform sampler2DArray textures;
// uniform vec3 fcolor;

// Output color
layout(location = 0) out  vec4 color;

void main()
{

    color = texture(textures, vec3(uvcoord.x, uvcoord.y, 0.0));


}
```

Vertex Shader

```
#version 330 
// Input attributes
in vec2 in_position;
in vec2 in_uvcoord;
in vec2 in_centre_pos;

// Passed to fragment shader
out vec2 uvcoord;
out vec2 vpos;

// Application data
uniform mat3 transform;
uniform mat3 projection;

void main()
{
    uvcoord = in_uvcoord;
    vpos = in_position;
    vec3 pos = projection * vec3(in_position.x + in_centre_pos.x, in_position.y + in_centre_pos.y, 1.0);
    gl_Position = vec4(pos.x, pos.y, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification; 8.19. IMMUTABLE-FORMAT TEXTURE IMAGES; page 272](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf):

> The `TexStorage*` commands specify properties of the texture object bound to the target parameter of each command.
>
> .....
>
> Errors
>
> An INVALID_ENUM error is generated if internalformat is one of the **unsized base internal formats** listed in table 8.11.

This means it is not allowed to use `GL_RGBA` for the 3rd paramter of [`glTexStorage3D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexStorage3D.xhtml).

Use `GL_RGBA8` instead:

```
glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL_RGBA8, 50, 50, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the enum error! My problem now is that I'm not sure how to splice my texture atlas into individual texture layers using glTexStorage3D. I changed my call to:
`glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL_RGBA8, 672, 736, 1);`
So it matches the width and height of my texture image. However, my texture image is made up of 483 32x32 pixel tiles and when i do:
`glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL_RGBA8, 32, 32, 483);`
I get an INVALID_VALUE error. Am I not setting the parameters correctly?

Comment: @danbrodsky I can't see any obvious issue. An INVALID_VALUE is generated if width, height, depth or levels are less than 1.

Answer (score 0):

You specified OpenGL 3.2, in this version function `glTexStorage3D` does not exist. Use `glTexImage3D`, which works with `GL_RGBA` instead of sized format `GL_RGBA8` required by storage functions.